# How do I remove and add Array elements within an Object used for State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create this function that can be used to add **this.state.user.id** to **this.state.players.team1** while also checking through all other arrays within **this.state.players** to remove the **this.state.user.id** if it is existing.

Here is some context:

```
// function is used for onClick()
// this.state.players = { 
//     team1: [1, 2], 
//     team2: [5, 7] 
// }
// this.state.user.id = 7
// (team) parameter is passed with "team1" or "team2" depending on situation
```

Below is the function I've attempted to write.
Is there a better way to write this out? this.setState performs asynchronously which breaks my function.

```
onJoinTeam(team) {

    // remove player id from any id
    this.setState({
        players: 
            Object.entries(this.state.players).map(key => {
                return key[1].filter(player => player !== this.state.user.id)
            })
    })

    // add this.state.user.id to this.state.players
    this.setState({  
        players: { 
            ...this.state.players, 
            [team]: [ ...this.state.players[team], this.state.user.id ], 
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Create the entire new `players` object first. Then use a single `setState` call. A different but worse way is to use the fact that `setState` accepts a callback that runs after the state change and change the state a 2nd time in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution, not so straightforward maybe not so readable but it works :)
Using `Object.entries` we create a map. While doing this we are checking if `team` is equal to our `key`. If yes, we add our `id` to our `key`, if not we filter out the `id`. The last step is to create an object using this array with `reduce`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    players: {
      team1: [1, 2],
      team2: [5, 7],
      team3: [9, 6, 7],
    },
    id: 7,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.change( "team1" );
  }

  change = team => {
    const { players, id } = this.state;
    const newPlayers = Object.entries(players).map(([key,value]) =>
      team === key
        ? { [key] : [ ...value, id ] }
        : { [key]: value.filter(player => player !== id) }
    ).reduce( ( obj, item) => ({
      ...obj,
      ...item,
    }) );
    
    this.setState({players: newPlayers})
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.state.players );
    return (
         <div>
         Look the console to see the old and new value of the players.
         </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for. It works for my setup but I agree with you it is not pretty to look at. Im going to try and boil this down further but any more help would be appreciated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution after reading through all of your ideas. Here is what I have now:

```
onJoinTeam(team) {
    const { players } = this.state;
    const newTeams = {}
    Object.entries(players).map(([key, value]) => {
        const filteredTeamObj = { 
            [key]: value.filter(player => player !== this.state.user.id) }
        return Object.assign(newTeams, filteredTeamObj)
    })
    this.setState({
        players: { 
            ...newTeams, 
            [team]: [ ...this.state.players[team], this.state.user.id ], 
        }
    })
}
```

Thanks again everyone

Comment: Nice combination there :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
const { players } = this.state;

for (const team in players) {
  const teamPlayers = players[team];
  const playerIndex = teamPlayers.findIndex(tp => tp === userId);

  if (playerIndex !== -1) {
    teamPlayers.splice(playerIndex, 1);
    break;
  }
}

players[newTeam].push(userId);

this.setState({ players });
```

Can see in action in this snippet

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    players: {
      team1: [1, 2, 3],
      team2: [4, 5, 6],
    },
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 4)}</pre>

        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.onJoinTeam(e)}>
          <label>User ID</label>
          <input name="userId" type="number" min="1" max="6" step="1" />
          <br />
          <label>New Team</label>
          <select name="newTeam">
            <option value="team1">Team 1</option>
            <option value="team2">Team 2</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Move player</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onJoinTeam(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newTeam = e.currentTarget.newTeam.value;
    const userId = parseInt(e.currentTarget.userId.value, 10);

    const { players } = this.state;

    for (const team in players) {
      const teamPlayers = players[team];
      const playerIndex = teamPlayers.findIndex(tp => tp === userId);

      if (playerIndex !== -1) {
        teamPlayers.splice(playerIndex, 1);
        break;
      }
    }

    players[newTeam].push(userId);

    this.setState({ players });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This solution is awesome but I can't use it in my setup. I have a mapping function that renders content along with the buttons depending on how many team there are. Your code is duplicating my state whenever I click a different Join Team button. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @kayq I don't know what "duplicating my state" means, but I cant see a reason for why this won't work with multiple buttons.

Comment: @EdwardSammutAlessi, you are mutating the original state here. Destructing `players` from state, then changing its property also changes the original `players` here. Even you use something like spread syntax like `const state = { ...this.state.player }` this does not work since spread syntax makes a shallow copy only, again changing a property mutates the original object. Also, `splice` changes the original array, this is the second mutating. The easiest way is doing a deep clone something like that: `const players = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.players));`

Comment: Also, if you use `break` in the if statemant (I don't understand why) breaks the code for the players object who has elements greater than 2.

Comment: You are correct that I am mutating original state but for my example, it doesn't really matter. Opted for brevity.